# How to stop in HandlerInterceptor execution flow and write ResponseEntity back to the client?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, http-headers

I have a simple REST API and I would like to stop an execution flow in my interceptor class that implements Spring's `org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor` and I need to write to the client `org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<T>` with the JSON response.

That is because I need to check in my interceptor if a client can consume the resource and if he is not authenticated I need to stop the flow and return some JSON meta information + proper HTTP status.

Is it good idea? and:

- if so - how to write to the client `ResponseEntity<T>`?
- if not - what is better way to return `ResponseEntity<T>` back to the client and stop the execution flow?

Answer (score 2):

you could throw an `Exception` in your `HandlerInterceptor` and have a `@ExceptionHandler` annotated method in a `@Controller` handle it.